# How can I make ggvis legend match the graph?

Tags: r, ggvis

I have created a function which uses ggvis to graph some of the data we review regularly.  In this, the final group, "Overall" is overwritten to show as a black line with a width of 3 instead of the default.  Unfortunately, the steps I have taken to override the default do not show in the legend.  I am unsure what to do to make this work.  I have attempted to specifically call the add_legend, but that did not work.

[image: S.O. Line Graph]

The code used to generate this is (also with some random data):

```
CAL_DATE = seq(as.Date("10/1/2015", format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
               as.Date("3/31/2016", format = "%m/%d/%Y"), by = 1)
CAL_DATE = as.POSIXct(CAL_DATE)
a = data.frame(cbind(ma_AHT = round(rweibull(length(CAL_DATE),
                                       5, 500),0), CT_DS = rep("A",length(CAL_DATE))))
b = data.frame(cbind(ma_AHT = round(rweibull(length(CAL_DATE),
                                       4, 540),0), CT_DS = rep("B", length(CAL_DATE))))
Overall = data.frame(cbind(ma_AHT = round(rweibull(length(CAL_DATE),
                                             10, 475),0), CT_DS = rep("Overall", length(CAL_DATE))))
a$CAL_DATE = CAL_DATE
b$CAL_DATE = CAL_DATE
Overall$CAL_DATE = CAL_DATE

data = rbind(a, b, Overall)

plot_ma = function(x){
        x %>%
                group_by(CT_DS) %>%
                ggvis(~CAL_DATE, ~ma_AHT, stroke = ~CT_DS) %>%
                layer_lines() %>%
                filter(CT_DS == "Overall") %>%
                layer_lines(stroke := "black", strokeWidth := 3) %>%
                set_options(renderer = "canvas") %>%
                add_legend("stroke", title = "~ CT") %>%
                add_axis("x", title = "Date", title_offset = 60,
                         properties = axis_props(
                                 labels = list(
                                         angle = -50,
                                         align = "right",
                                         baseline = "middle"
                                 ))) %>%
                add_axis("y", title = "M.A. AHT (sec)")
}
plot_ma(data)
```

Which should generate something like below.  My only concern is how to make the legend show 'Overall' as black also.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a small example dataset?

Comment: If `Overall` is always going to be last I think you could just define the colors in `scale_nominal` via `range`.  In your simple example it would be something like `scale_nominal("stroke", range = c("blue", "orange", "black"))`.  For more groups, you could make a vector of colors or pull colors out of a sample for the number of groups you have and then append "black" on to the end.

Comment: The number of groups could vary widely between data sets.  Could you give me more insight into how to pull colors out of the sample?  I looked inside a ggvis object to try and find where it might be but did not have success.

Answer (score 1):

Using `scale_nominal` and providing the `range` allows you to set the colors in both the graphic and the legend.

In your simple example, this is as easy as adding, e.g.,
`scale_nominal("stroke", range = c("blue", "orange", "black"))`
to the end of your plotting code.

It sounds like the number of groups may vary.  However, of the `Overall` group is always last in order (or you set it to be last via `factor`), you can use something similar to above and make it part of your function.  In this case, you'll want to establish a color palette that you like (and that doesn't contain black) that has enough colors for all of your groups.

Here I'll take one of the palettes given at [Cookbook for R](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_%28ggplot2%29/) with 8 different colors.

```
cbPalette = c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")
```

We can pull out the number of colors needed from the palette for a particular dataset by using the number of levels of the grouping factor.  The number of colors needed is this minus 1, as the last one will always be black.

Here's one way to calculate the number of groups need to color minus 1.

```
ncol = nlevels(data[["CT_DS"]]) - 1
```

This info can be used to pull out the first 1 to "number of levels minus 1" colors from `cbPalette`.

```
pal = cbPalette[1:ncol]
```

This can be used for the `range` argument of `scale_nominal`, appending `"black"` on to the end of the vector.

`scale_nominal("stroke", range = c(pal, "black"))`

This process is easily added in to your function.

```
plot_ma = function(x){
    ncol = nlevels(x[["CT_DS"]]) - 1
    pal = cbPalette[1:ncol]
    x %>%
        group_by(CT_DS) %>%
        ggvis(~CAL_DATE, ~ma_AHT, stroke = ~CT_DS) %>%
        layer_lines() %>%
        filter(CT_DS == "Overall") %>%
        layer_lines(stroke := "black", strokeWidth := 3) %>%
        set_options(renderer = "canvas") %>%
        add_legend("stroke", title = "~ CT") %>%
        add_axis("x", title = "Date", title_offset = 60,
                properties = axis_props(
                    labels = list(
                        angle = -50,
                        align = "right",
                        baseline = "middle"
                    ))) %>%
        add_axis("y", title = "M.A. AHT (sec)") %>%
        scale_nominal("stroke", range = c(pal, "black"))
}
plot_ma(data)
```

[image]

Comment: It works just as you described @aosmith.  Thank you.